# php foreach results

Tags: php, foreach

```
      foreach ($flr_array as $flr) {
          if (!($flr = trim($flr)))
              continue;
          //list($flr, $keyword) = explode('|', $flr, 2);
          $ip = '';
          $err_msg = isValidFLR($flr, $ip);
          if (!$err_msg) {
              list($randlink, $lastid, $scr) = addLink($flr, $ip);
              $flr = stripslashes($flr);
              $url_array[$i]['number'] = $i + 1;
              $url_array[$i]['flr'] = $flr;
              $url_array[$i]['flr_substr'] = (strlen($flr) > 33) ? substr($flr, 0, 33) . '...' : $flr;
              $url_array[$i]['randlink'] = $randlink;
              $url_array[$i]['fullrand'] = $config['indexurl'] . $config['mod_rewrite_char'] . $randlink;
              $url_array[$i]['scr'] = $scr;
              $url_array[$i]['id'] = $lastid;
              $url_array[$i]['flr_length'] = strlen($flr);
              $url_array[$i++]['randlink_length'] = strlen($config['indexurl'] . $config['mod_rewrite_char'] . $randlink);
              ////
              //$smarty->assign("flr_length", strlen($_REQUEST['flr']));
              //$smarty->assign("randlink_length", strlen($config['indexurl'] . $config['mod_rewrite_char'] . $randlink));
              ////
          } else {
                  js_alert($err_msg);
              }
      }
```

In function **isValidFLR**  these is part of captcha check:

```
if ($config['captcha_check']) {
    if (verifyCaptcha() == false) {
        return 'Wrong code!';
    }
}
```

Let's say in textarea i enter:

1. google.com
2. google.de
3. google.net

and enter wrong captcha code, so it gives me **3 messages** of Wrong code!
It's happen i think because of foreach. Any ideas how to make in foreach display only one error message ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `if (!($flr === trim($flr)))
`? (notice `===`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand but I think you are right (in the foreach)....

if err_msg <> '' then you should put a `break` in your code to get out of the foreach (if that is what you want).

Comment: Ahh, sorry, my english language not primary. By the way, break does what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 else {
js_alert($err_msg);
break; //this will break out of for loop
//or return false if it a function

}
```